# I am getting bad request error in my ajax post response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append my ajax response into data table.
I am using ajax inside the Data table.

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
              processing: true,
              serverSide: true,
             "ajax": {
    "url": "https://2057-185-202-239-227.ngrok.io/employee/employeesByCompany",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "type": "POST",
    "dataSrc" : "doc",
    "data": JSON.stringify({"company" : "6249fdf91399dc7a14173dcd"})
  },
            columns: [
                { doc: 'createdDate' },
                { doc: 'CNIC' },
                { doc: 'employeeID' },
                { doc: 'fName' },
                { doc: 'fatherName' }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{ /* default values for columns */
                "defaultContent": "-",
                "targets": "_all"
            }],
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

the above is my ajax request where I am Posting company id to my APIto retrieve data from API but getting error

This is the error I am getting in my console tab developer options:
POST https://2057-185-202-239-227.ngrok.io/employee/employeesByCompany 400

Comment: you are getting a 404 not found which means that the server doesn't have the route :"/employee/employeesByCompany"

Comment: but this route is working properly in my postman. What would be its fix Ithink I am following wrong syantax

Comment: Are you sending a POST request in Postman too, or a GET or some other HTTP verb? Does the error message in the console mention CORS at all?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using POST request with some data in postman too and I am not getting any error over there